# Angular table doesn't show data

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm making a time logging app as an exercise. I'm facing a problem, when I'm trying to display all the entries on a table (image below, there should be two entries according to console). It creates the entries' amount of rows, but it doesn't display any data on the cells. Been struggling with this for a while, what am I doing wrong?

[image: Table not showing data, but creates rows. By default it should show entries for current week. According to console there should be 2 entries.]

Code:

**dashboard.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="user">
  <h4 style="margin-top: 2%">Past workhours</h4>
  <form (submit)="getLogs(user.username, startDate, endDate)">
    <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
        <label>Search workhours between</label>
        <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="inputStartDate">From:</label>
          <input 
            type="Date" 
            class="form-control" 
            id="inputStartDate" 
            name="startDate"
            [(ngModel)]="startDate"
            >
          </td>
        <td>
          <label for="inputEndDate">To:</label>
          <input 
            type="Date" 
            class="form-control" 
            id="inputEndDate" 
            name="endDate"
            [(ngModel)]="endDate"
          >
        </td>
        <td>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Date</th>
          <th scope="col">Hours</th>
          <th scope="col">Minutes</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let arr of log" >
          <td>{{log.date}}</td>
          <td>{{log.hours}}</td>
          <td>{{log.minutes}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
```

**dashboard.component.ts** (excluded code not related to the issue)

```
  export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  user: Object;
  log: any;

  username: String;
  date: Date;
  hours: number;
  minutes: number;

  constructor(
    private validateService: ValidateService,
    private flashMessage: FlashMessagesService,
    private authService: AuthService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // default dates, ongoing week's Monday and Sunday
    const today = new Date(); // get today date
    const first = today.getDate() - today.getDay() + 1;
    const last = first + 6;

    const defaultEndDate = new Date(today.setDate(last)).toISOString().split("T")[0]; // Sunday of current week
    const defaultStartDate = new Date(today.setDate(first)).toISOString().split("T")[0]; // Monday of current week

    this.authService.getProfile().subscribe(profile => {
      this.user = profile.user;
      this.getLogs(profile.user.username, defaultStartDate, defaultEndDate);
    },
    err => {
      console.log(err);
      return false;
    });
  }

  getLogs(username, startDate, endDate) {
    this.authService.getLog(username).subscribe(workhour => {
      // Put entries into array 'log' with a for-loop
      // Probably not the most efficient way of doing this, 
      // but it is something came up with quickly
      this.log = []; // empty array at the start of the function
      var j = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < workhour.length; i++) {
        const tempDate = workhour[i].date.split("T")[0];
          if (tempDate >= startDate && tempDate <= endDate) {
            var tempHour;
            var tempMinutes;
            
            if (workhour[i].hours % 60 === 0) {
              tempHour = workhour[i].hours/60;
            tempMinutes = 0;
          } else {
            tempHour = (workhour[i].hours - workhour[i].hours % 60)/60;
            tempMinutes = workhour[i].hours % 60;
          }
          
          this.log[j] = {date: tempDate, hours: tempHour, minutes: tempMinutes};
          console.log(this.log[j]);
          j++;
        }
      };
      this.log.sort().reverse();
      console.log(this.log);
      if (this.log.length === 0) this.flashMessage.show('No entries found for the set range', {cssClass: 'alert-danger', timeout: 3000}); 
    },
    err => {
      console.log(err);
      return false;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to use arr instead of log inside your ngFor loop.

```
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let arr of log" >
      <td>{{arr.date}}</td>
      <td>{{arr.hours}}</td>
      <td>{{arr.minutes}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Didn't think of this small mistake I made...

Comment: Happened to me more often, than I like to admit :)

Answer (score 2):

You have declared an `arr` variable in your `*ngFor` directive but you call the `{{log.date}}`

```
<tr *ngFor="let arr of log">
      <td>{{ arr.date }}</td>
      <td>{{ arr.hours }}</td>
      <td>{{ arr.minutes }}</td>
</tr>
```

Verify that your table contains data.